# Xcode Button Click Alpha

Tags: iphone, xcode, image, button, alpha

Basically I am trying to make a button shaped as a circle and add an image to it. The image is a png with transparency representing a sphere. Adding it to a custom button does it, but it has one problem. The transparent content around the sphere is also clickable. How Do I make so that the nontransparent area of the image is clickable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out GKTank sample for how to register and use touches.

You have to have to register to get the touch events, then inside the event, check the location, and decide if it is hitting your graphic.  To do that, you would have to know the dimmentions and shape of the round button, and then decide if the touch is inside or outside of it.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (myButtonIsActive) {
        CGPoint tPoint;
        UITouch *thumb = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
        tPoint = [thumb locationInView:thumb.view];
        // check here if tPoint is inside of the button shape/circle
```